# slow select query in a big table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've a problem with an enormous table in a database of an RoR application.
This is a part of my MySql database:

TABLE DEVICES:

`create_table "devices", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "mac"
  end`

TABLE EVENTS:

```
create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.integer  "device_id"
    t.string   "data_type"
    t.integer  "element_id"
    ...
end
```

A device has_many events, so this table is very big.

the problem is when i want to find a record in this table by this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
    element_id, 
    created_at, 
    device_id, 
    multimedia_id 
FROM events 
WHERE device_id = N 
  AND data_type = 'S' 
  AND element_id = N 
LIMIT N
```

the problem is:
No index was used here. In this case, that meant scanning 930447 rows..

In fact, the primary key in "id".

What can i do?
I had to think about:

1. change the primary key but RoR have no Composite Primary Key.
2. divide the events table in many table, one for each device. How? What will the association become? (Table `has_many` ?)
3. can i link a table by a string? for example   `"Events".where(...)` ?

can anyone help me?

Sorry for my English. bye.
Davide Lentini

Comment: add the output of `explain <your query here>` to your post.

Comment: how to use the explain command?

Comment: I recommend learning some basic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you should not use composite primary key doesn't mean you can't add a composite index (in a new migration):

```
def self.up
  add_index :events, [:device_id, :data_type, :element_id], :name => 'my_events_index'
end

def self.down
  remove_index :events, :name => 'my_events_index'
end
```

Comment: i've anothe problem with optimization, i have a query in the same table that order records by "created_at". 
What can i do to speedup it?

Comment: the query is:
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`device_id` = N AND `events`.`data_type` = 'S' AND (`events`.`created_at` BETWEEN 'S' AND 'S') ORDER BY events.created_at ASC LIMIT N

Answer (score 1):

Why not just creating an index over the columns `device_id, data_type, element_id` ?